# vim-haskellmode and hsenv

Tags: haskell, vim, cabal

I've been using [hsenv](https://github.com/Paczesiowa/hsenv) (with great success!)
to deal with the usual cabal dependency issues.

Its terrific, but there is one glitch I can't get around: how to persuade the 
(also excellent!) [vim-haskellmode](http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/) to use the environment  variables set by hsenv -- namely the paths to GHC, cabal database and so on 
when compiling, generating tags etc.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You're supposed to answer your own question if the question was worth asking :)

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and don't delete your question otherwise nobody will ever be able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, hit the wrong button -- I should be asking questions about how to use SO instead :)

Anyways, an even better trick is to put this into the .vimrc

```
let g:ghc=system("which ghc")
```

This way (assuming that `g:ghc` gets bound when you run vim) it will pick up whichever `ghc` 
is being currently used (by hsenv).

Ranjit Jhala.

Answer (score 1):

One, simple solution is to hack one's .vimrc so that

```
let g:ghc="/path/to/hsenv/ghc"
```